# Cannot resolve symbol EnumerableEx

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive, permutation

This is bugging me ... I'm writing a quick permutation tool and used the NuGet package manager  and installed the Reactive LINQ extensions but the example code I've been experimenting with:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permutations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> xs)
    {
        if (!xs.Any())
            return EnumerableEx.Return(Enumerable.Empty<T>());
        else
            return from zs in Permutations(xs.Skip(1))
                   from i in Enumerable.Range(0, zs.Count() + 1)
                   select zs.Take(i).Concat(EnumerableEx.Return(xs.First())).Concat(zs.Skip(i));
    }
}
```

Won't compile because the symbol 'EnumerableEx' can't be resolved.  What namespace is this referenced in?  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution of Interactive Extensions (backported extensions for `IEnumerable`) was separated after gold release of Reactive Extensions.

Just install NuGet package `Install-Package Ix_Experimental-Main` it'll work again.